# Very strange error with NSOperationQueue

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsoperationqueue

I have the following code:

```
- (void)readSettingsFiles
{
    NSOperationQueue *operationQueue = [[[NSOperationQueue alloc] init] autorelease];
    [operationQueue setName:@"File Parsing Queue"];

    if (urlForV1SettingsFile) {
        [operationQueue addOperationWithBlock:^{
            SettingsReader *settingsReader = [[[SettingsReader alloc] initWithURL:urlForV1SettingsFile] autorelease];
            NSArray *settings = [settingsReader settings];
            [settingsToSave addObjectsFromArray:settings];
        }];
    }

    if (urlForV2SettingsFile) {
        [operationQueue addOperationWithBlock:^{
            SettingsReader *settingsReader = [[[SettingsReader alloc] initWithURL:urlForV2SettingsFile] autorelease];
            NSArray *settings = [settingsReader settings];
            [settingsToSave addObjectsFromArray:settings];
        }];
    }

    while ([operationQueue operationCount] > 0) {
        sleep(1);
    }
}
```

`SettingsReader` is an NSXMLParser delegate that handles reading two different XML files. `settingsToSave` is a property of the class where this method is declared, type NSDictionary.

I have the sleep so the method won't return until all files have been parsed.

The problem is, when I exit the while loop I get this error in the console:

```
objc[74760]: Class _NSZombie_NSCFInputStream is implemented in both ?? and ??. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
```

Never seen it before, neither has Google. Any help?

Comment: For clarification, is this a build for spotting zombies? Unrelated, I don't understand why you use an `NSOperationQueue` if you wait for it anyways. Also, is `settingsToSave` a member variable?

Comment: You shouldn’t update your `settingsToSave` array from multiple threads at the same time, this does not work. Also, use `waitUntilAllOperationsAreFinished` instead of that `sleep` loop.

Comment: Are you using a category?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm betting that this means that two threads have done the zombie-detection munging dance on NSInputStream simultaneously. I suspect if you didn't execute these in parallel, this wouldn't happen. I wouldn't worry about it.

Answer (score 1):

For one thing, mutable classes are not thread safe. So you should set max concurrent to 1.

```
[operationQueue setMaxConcurrentOperationCount:1];
```

or

```
@synchronized(settingsToSave) {
    [settingsToSave addObjectsFromArray:settings];
}
```

Also, having your variable name settings the same as the method name settings probably isn't the best idea for readability.

Of greater note, why are you using an operationsqueue at all here? None of these operations are asynchronous. And if you are blocking the main thread til they complete anyway, I don't see any benefit to all the overhead of launching up an NSOperationQueue and background threads. Why not just:

```
if (urlForV1SettingsFile) {
        SettingsReader *settingsReader1 = [[[SettingsReader alloc] initWithURL:urlForV1SettingsFile] autorelease];
        NSArray *settings1 = [settingsReader1 settings];
        [settingsToSave addObjectsFromArray:settings1];
}

if (urlForV2SettingsFile) {
        SettingsReader *settingsReader2 = [[[SettingsReader alloc] initWithURL:urlForV2SettingsFile] autorelease];
        NSArray *settings2 = [settingsReader2 settings];
        [settingsToSave addObjectsFromArray:settings2];
}
```

So much simpler...